# Error al mostrar listado con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo

Hola estoy tratando de mostrar un listado el cual me mostraba con 'myslqi' ahora estoy trabajando con PDO pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar el error que me genera no lo entiendo.

```
function listadoUsuarios(){
    $db = new BaseDatos();
    $db->conectar();

    $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM Usuario";

    $db->prepare($sentencia);
    $sentencia->execute();

    echo "<div id='listado'>";
        echo "<table id='listadoUsuario' border=1 cellspacing=0>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>".'Nombre completo'."</th>";  
                echo "<th>".'Correo'."</th>";  
                echo "<th>".'Teléfono'."</th>";  
                echo "<th>".'Dirección'."</th>";
                echo "<th>".'Fecha de nacimiento'."</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while ($row = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){     
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['nombre'].', '.$row['apellido']."</td>";  
                    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";  
                    echo "<td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['direccion'].', '.$row['cod_postal']."</td>";  
                    echo "<td>".$row['fecha_nac'].' - '."</td>";
                    echo "<td><button class='btn_tabla'><a href='google.es'>Modificar</a></button></td>";
                    echo "<td><button class='btn_tabla_mal'><a href='google.es'>Eliminar</a></button></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }  
        echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";

}
```

Comment: Olvidaste poner lo más importante: **el error que te genera**, ¿cuál es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en el código:

1. **No estás recuperando el resultado de preparar y ejecutar, en el cual tendrías un conjunto de resultados** que luego podrías leer con uno de los métodos `fetch` más adelante.

   Algo así:

   ```
   $resultado=$db->prepare($sentencia);
   $resultado=->execute();
   ```

   Y luego para leer:

   ```
       while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   ```
2. Por lo que has comentado sobre el error `Call to undefined method BaseDatos::query()`, se puede ver que tampoco estás recuperando una instancia de tu conexión PDO, la cual sería devuelta por el método `conectar`.

### También...

En este caso no necesitas preparar la consulta, ya que en ella **no hay nada que preparar**, porque no intervienen datos desde el exterior.

Entonces, puedes hacerlo con `query`:

```
function listadoUsuarios(){
    $pdo = new BaseDatos(); //Hay un cambio aquí
    $db=$pdo->conectar();   //Hay un cambio aquí

    $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM Usuario";

    $resultado=$db->query($sentencia); //Hay un cambio aquí

    echo "<div id='listado'>";
        echo "<table id='listadoUsuario' border=1 cellspacing=0>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>".'Nombre completo'."</th>";  
                echo "<th>".'Correo'."</th>";  
                echo "<th>".'Teléfono'."</th>";  
                echo "<th>".'Dirección'."</th>";
                echo "<th>".'Fecha de nacimiento'."</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ //Hay un cambio aquí    
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['nombre'].', '.$row['apellido']."</td>";  
                    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";  
                    echo "<td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['direccion'].', '.$row['cod_postal']."</td>";  
                    echo "<td>".$row['fecha_nac'].' - '."</td>";
                    echo "<td><button class='btn_tabla'><a href='google.es'>Modificar</a></button></td>";
                    echo "<td><button class='btn_tabla_mal'><a href='google.es'>Eliminar</a></button></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }  
        echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";

}
```

Comment: Hola acabo de probar los cambios y parece que algunos error desaparecen. Ahora me da este error Fatal error: Call to undefined method BaseDatos::prepare() in le cual no entiendo pues a mi parecer tendría que estar definida.

Comment: @sergibarca no entiendo por qué debería darte ese error, si te fijas, estamos usando `query()`, no `prepare()`, precisamente porque aquí las consultas preparadas no aplican. ¿Probaste el código como lo he puesto en mi respuesta? ¿Ese error no vendrá de otra parte de tu programa?

Comment: si perdona el error es BaseDatos::query()

Comment: Parece que hay un problema con tu clase `BaseDatos`. ¿El método `conectar()` de la misma tiene un `return` que devuelve un objeto PDO válido? Si es así, entonces deberías poner algo como: `$pdo = new BaseDatos();
    $db=$pdo->conectar();`  El problema parece ser que en tu código actual la variable `$db` no obtiene nunca un objeto PDO y por eso dice que el método no existe.

Comment: @sergibarca si no funciona como te digo en mi anterior comentario, por favor comparte el código del método `conectar()` de tu clase `BaseDatos` (puedes quitar las contraseñas y datos de usuario si los hubiera).

Comment: Hola si me funciona era exactamente eso. Lo que no entiendo es por que al crear el obj con el nombre $pdo funciona... Muchísimas gracias

Comment: @sergibarca es que la instancia de la conexión es devuelta cuando llamas al método `conectar()`, y no estabas almacenando dicha instancia para luego usarla. O sea, haciendo esto solamente: `$db->conectar();`, usabas la instancia de la clase para llamar al método de conexión, pero eso no significaba que `$db` fuese una instancia de tu conexión PDO, sino una instancia de tu clase `BaseDatos`... son dos cosas distintas.

Comment: Vale me acabas de iluminar! jeje Muchas gracias, he aprendido con vuestros aportes, muchas gracias. :)

Comment: @sergibarca me alegro de que te haya servido. He actualizado la respuesta para que quede la solución completa por si puede servir a otros. Saludos y hasta la próxima en Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que `$sentencia` es un string y no tiene un método `prepare`. Lo que debes hacer es asignar la salida de `$db->prepare` a una variable (que es un PDOStatement)

```
$sentencia = "SELECT * FROM Usuario";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sentencia);
$stmt->execute();
```

Y luego iterar usando `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.

Eso respecto a tu código tal como lo tienes ahora. En caso que no estés usando parámetros para tu consulta, [A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) tiene razón, no hay nada que preparar.